# Plugins from Different Eclipse Configuration are not Isolated

Tags: eclipse

I'm sorry for a pretty vague title, didn't want to turn it into a paragraph.

So, I am using Eclipse Platform 3.7.1 (the one with absolutely no plugin preinstalled), the latest version so far, and I have discovered that by taking advantage of its -configuration option, I can choose which plugins are running and which are not. It was going well enough until I started installing the plugins.

But allow me to explain my setup first, I am using Ubuntu linux by the way. Using only one eclipse installation, my installation is arranged in the following order:

```
Installation:
  ~/bin/opt/eclipse
      eclipse (executable binary)
  ~/bin/eclipse -> opt/eclipse/eclipse

Configurations:
  ~/.eclipse/configuration
    web-php
    android
    java
```

Installing JDT and ADT while running eclipse and using the android configuration directory posed no problems. So I moved on to the php configuration and tried to install PDT (the JDT and ADT plugins were not activated here, so far so good). The problems came along after the installation, not only was I not able to use PDT, I noticed in the Installation Details that JDT, ADT, PDT were installed but not activated. Instead, they were all activated in the android configuration. To make it worse, when I chose the Java configuration, I could not even use JDT.

My expectations however were when using:

```
eclipse -configuration ~/.eclipse/configuration/android
```

was that only the JDT and ADT were activated and when using:

```
eclipse -configuration ~/.eclipse/configuration/web-php
```

only the PDT is activated

Regarding the java configuration however, it's probably another problem altogether but if there was help on how to activate a plugin installed from another configuration, I'd deeply appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, see [Single Eclipse install with multiple Configurations and Workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053887/single-eclipse-install-with-multiple-configurations-and-workspaces)

In a p2 world there are extra steps to isolate bundles from each other.  You need not just a different configuration directory, but a different p2 profile.

Comment: This one worked like a charm, and I don't mind having to install the same plugin over and over again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the config.ihi in each of your configurations. There are two ways that Eclipse identifies the plugins to use, the ..updateconfigurator, which simply uses all of the plugins in the plugins folder, and the ..simpleconfigurator which uses the bundles.info file in that's in the org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator folder (which is maintained by the p2 installer). Make sure this file is what you expect.

And also, you might want to start with the -clean option if you are using the updateconfigurator to have it rescan all of the plugins (otherwise it remembers in some hidden cache).

Make sure when you installed everything that you had your -configuration set to the right place for the different things you installed.

I hope some of this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Really appreciate it! I'll take a look at this as soon I get some free time. Might take a while though.